# How to update ALL data in database1 from data in database2?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Please Help me. how to update ALL data database1 from database2?
QUERY TO UPDATE THIS DATABASE1
i have two database  :
1. database1, table product :

```
================================
| model  | pricelow | pricehigh|
================================
| A2345  | 64       |   74     |
| A2350  | 50       |   60     |


database1

=====================================================
model_master | pricelow_master | pricehigh_master |
=====================================================
|A2345       | 70              |    80            |
|A2350       | 60              |    65            |

database2
```

Comment: Probably easiest to just select all your values from the first table, make whatever changes you need to in your php script. Then insert them back into the second table.What are you actually trying to update?

Comment: your earlier post was better. please dont paste images.you data to be copied from table 2 to table1,correct?

Comment: Update. How to query for update database1? I'm sorry i edit my question

Comment: Try this: if insert - `INSERT INTO product (model, pricelow, pricehigh) VALUES (SELECT model_master, pricelow_master, pricehigh_master FROM product_master)`

Answer (score 1):

You need an unique key for update. Here i use `id`.

Try this may be helpful to you.

**For Update:**

```
UPDATE database1 p, database2 pm SET 
p.model = pm.model_master,
p.pricelow = pm.pricelow_master,
p.pricehigh = pm.pricehigh_master,
WHERE p.id = pm.id
```

**For Insert:**

```
INSERT INTO database1 (model, pricelow, pricehigh) SELECT model_master, pricelow_master, pricehigh_master FROM database2
```

Comment: what is "p" in product p?

Comment: the new name of product for this query.

Comment: You can also use this like: `product AS p`.

Comment: sir, database1 update from data in database2. so query for call database 1 & 2 how do it?

Comment: you just change your question. Use `database1` at `product` and `database2` at `product_master`.

Comment: I think the insert query should be `INSERT INTO product (model, pricelow, pricehigh) SELECT model_master, pricelow_master, pricehigh_master FROM product_master`

Comment: UPDATE DatabaseA.dbo.tableA SET DatabaseA.dbo.tableA.Name=TEST.Name FROM (SELECT * FROM DatabaseB.dbo.tableA) AS TEST WHERE DatabaseA.dbo.tableA.ID = TEST.ID

not working too